# Impossible to copy paste wolfram script on windows command shell (cmd)

Tags: scripting

I am a full beginner in coding.

I have prepared some Wolfram script on the Mathematica platform. I would like to run it on Windows command shell.

Accordingly I have activated wolframscript on cmd, using the following command:

```
C:\Users\hugor\Documents\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.3>wolframscript
```

It seems to be working, and the following message pops up:

> Wolfram Language 12.3.1 Engine for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)
> Copyright 1988-2021 Wolfram Research, Inc.

I can now write my Wolfram script at the input prompt:

```
In[1]:=
```

My issue is, it is now impossible to paste anything (while it was possible to do so before I entered the command wolframscript)

Why is it so? My wolfram script is quite significant in size, it will be extremely time-consuming and error-prone to type it from scratch.

Similarly, it also becomes very difficult to type certain signs {[|` Here you might want to know that I'm using a French keyboard (which means I normally have to type ctrl+alt+5 to write "[", or ctlr+alt+0 to write "@".) If I click frantically, I do manage to type them, but with with insane difficulty.

Is this normal?

Comment: For pasting, you should be able to right-click (which should then directly paste the contents of the clipboard). As for the keyboard layout, I don't know (it also doesn't work for me). But why not just save your script to a file and run that? If you are anyway developing the script in Mathematica, this should be way easier

Comment: Try `Ctrl + Shift + v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I was working on this moments ago so Ctrl-C from the Mathematica window and pasted into the Windows cmd using the menu.

[image]

Le monde est grand, il doit y avoir un script pour le faire.